# How can I make sure that an Android crash report doesn't send me sensitive user data?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I'm developing an app for Android. It's still in its alpha phase so I'm pretty sure that there are some bugs I haven't found yet.

I'm planning to release it on the Google Play Store in a couple of weeks. I hope that some users find bugs that I couldn't find myself.

I'm worried about the data that gets sent to me when users send a crash report. My app requires users to enter their username and password in a `PreferenceFragment`. I want to make sure that I can't receive these credentials when users send such a report.

All other information is welcome, though. Is there a way to exclude this data from being sent?

Comment: WHy are you making them do that?  That's usually the wrong way to code things.  Usernames and passwords should never be saved, login tokens should instead.

Comment: Which tool will you use to catch the crash reports? Usually that tools (like bugsense, crashlytics...) only export the crash exception/log and the information about the device.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's a front-end for another website, of which I can't use tokens.

Comment: @SandroMachado I'm planning to use the 'stock' reporting tool, the one you can see [here](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/Android-SDK_Reading-Android-Market-Crash-Reports/Figure1.png)

Comment: Storing a password, in plain text, is a real bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stock` Android crash report tool only includes the crash stack trace, an optional user message and some statistics (device, android version, application version). So you don't need to do something to hide user sensitive information in crash reports sent by the stock android crash report tool.

I would recommended you to use more complex tools to catch crash reports, like Crashlytics or Bugsense.